# finding how many times an element has repeated in c

Tags: c, arrays

I've got a c study which it must print all the numbers in an array then how many times they repeated.

```
int lottery(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e,int f,int i,int count)
{
    printf("Enter the loop count:");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    a=time(NULL);
    srand(a);
    int genel[100][100];
    int hepsi[50]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49};
    count=0;
    for(e=0;e<=d-1;e++)
    {
       for(b=0;b<=5;b++)
        {
           genel[e][b]=(rand()%49+1);
           while(i>=0 && i<=49)
                {
                  if(genel[e][b]==hepsi[i])
                    {
                        count=count+1;
                    }
                else{
                        count=count;
                    }

                }
           printf("%d->%d\t",genel[e][b],count);
        }
    }

}
```

This doesnt work obviously. the output must be something like that 
1-->0  2-->3 3-->15 etc

TY for your help, cheers :)

Comment: "This doesn't work obviously" - better if you posted the actual results you get.  Add more details and you'll have better luck.

Comment: Having proper names for the variables and arguments (some which I don't understand why you pass as argumentsin the first place) will help others better understand the code (and with "other" I also mean *you* in a couple of months, or even weeks, time).

Comment: `while(i>=0 && i<=49)`, ok, do you have any future plans to modify `i`?

Comment: Program should generate some random numbers between 1-49. I tried to add a output img but the site didnt allow me to, anyway. After generating some numbers it should print all numbers and how many times they has generated by the program. such as 12->5 that means 12 has generated 5 times.

Comment: @AlperenKarail i meant to say, you have one `while ()` infinite loop.

Comment: I know that but while i was trying to finish that code i changed it so many times to find the correct one. I just copied the wrong code up there. Btw i laughed at your comment though.

Comment: hepsi(that means all in turkish) is the array that keeps numbers of the lottery. genel(means general) is the array that program puts some random numbers in it. So i have to find for ex. "5" has been generated by program and print it like 5->2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important that you understand what you are doing, naming is therefore very important. Nesting loops is okay if you know what you are doing. An easier to understand approach would be:

```
void lottery() {
    int i, j                  //forloop counters
    int randArray[100][100];  //array for random values

    srand(Time(NULL));        //set random seed based on system time

    //set random values
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            randArray[i][j] = rand()%49 + 1; //sets random ranging from 1 to 49 (49 incl)
        }
    }

    //here you can start the counting procedure, which I won't spoil but ill give some hints below

}
```

There are a few options, first the easy lazy approach:
use a loop over all the values, 'int number' from 1 up to 49, inside that forloop use two forloops to search through the whole array, incrementing int x everytime you encounter the value 'number'. After youve searched through the whole array, you can use printf("%d -> %d", number, x); to print the value, set x to zero and count another number.

Another approach is as u tried,
create an array with for each number a location where you can increment a counter. Loop through the whole array now using two for-loops, increment the arraylocation corresponding to the value which youve found at randArray[i][j]. Afterwards print the array with counts using another forloop.

I suggest you try to clean up your code and approach, try again and come back with problems you encounter. Good luck!

sorry if this wasn't helpful to you, I tried to spoil not too much because according to my own experience programming should be learned by making mistakes.

Comment: I'm appreciated for your help but the part that i cant do is the counting procedure. All my ideas was wrong now im trying to use your suggestions. Thanx!

Comment: If you encounter a problem, please feel free to ask for help/some more details.